# How can I implement a generic filter function?

Tags: go, generics, higher-order-functions

Suppose I'm implementing this function for filtering a Slice in Golang:

```
 func Filter(filter func(n int) bool) func(list []int) []int {
   return func(list []int) []int {
     r := make([]int, 0)
     for _, n := range list {
         if filter(n) {
             r = append(r, n)
         }
   }

     return r
 } 
}
```

To be used like this:

```
list := []int{1, 4, 3, 2, 7, 4, 9, 7}
r := Filter(func(n int) bool { return n > 3 })(list)

fmt.Println(r)
```

This works ok, but I have the following questions:

1. Am I supposed to use the full func syntax instead of a lambda style expression?
2. If I want my Filter to filter slices of ANY type, what return type should I use?

Thanks!

Comment: [Type parameters](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md) are coming.   Until then, use [reflect](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect) or follow the pattern in the [sort package](https://pkg.go.dev/sort#Interface).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As far as I know, no proposal for a more concise anonymous-function notation ("lambda") has been accepted yet.
2. The addition of [type parameters](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md) (a.k.a. generics) to the language is planned for early 2022 with the release of Go 1.18. Then, you'll be able to write the program below ([playground](https://go.dev/play/p/OTJHc8Xb2CZ)).

   If you can wait until then, do. At any rate, [using the `reflect` package](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=15m23s) and [peppering one's code with the empty `interface{}` and type assertions](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PAAkCSZUG1c&t=7m36s) are generally discouraged. One viable alternative until Go 1.18 would be to use [`go generate`](https://blog.golang.org/generate) to generate the different specializations (for `int`, `string`, etc.) you need.

   ```
   package main

   import "fmt"

   func Filter[T any](filter func(n T) bool) func(T []T) []T {
       return func(list []T) []T {
           r := make([]T, 0, len(list))
           for _, n := range list {
               if filter(n) {
                   r = append(r, n)
               }
           }
           return r
       }
   }

   func main() {
       list := []int{1, 4, 3, 2, 7, 4, 9, 7}
       r := Filter(func(n int) bool { return n > 3 })(list)
       fmt.Println(r)

       list2 := []string{"foo", "bar", "baz", "qux", "quux"}
       r2 := Filter(func(s string) bool { return len(s) <= 3 })(list2)
       fmt.Println(r2)
   }
   ```

Comment: This was going to make the language be "Go 2" - has that changed?

Comment: @torek Yes, the designers managed to change the proposal in such a way that the addition of generics to the language [won't compromise the Go 1.0 compatibility guarantee](https://go.googlesource.com/proposal/+/refs/heads/master/design/43651-type-parameters.md#abstract): *The design is fully backward compatible with Go 1.*